# How to check condition using For and If statement in SIL programming

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Hi I am trying to figure out the fallowing scenario using SIL Condition on Jira 
if any of the linked issue statuses is Rejected auto transition the current issue or neglect the transition

```
string value = linkedIssues(key);
 for (string link in linkissues) {
    if(%link%.status != "Rejected") {
       return false;
        } else {
       autotransition("Reject",key);
       boolean exists = true;
       }
}
```

Please sujjest the best way to check this

Answer (score 0):

SIL Condition doesn't really work that way.  It is used to decide whether a transition is visible to users (for instance if they have to have set the fixVersion before using the Complete transition, you could hide the Complete transition until the fixVersion was filled in).  In this instance the issue would only be rejected if somebody looked at it, which seems... strange.

Without understanding your use case, I would guess you'd be better off triggering the transition when the original issue is rejected:

```
string[] linkissues = linkedIssues(key);
for (string link in linkissues) {
    if(%link%.status != "Rejected") {
        autotransition("Reject", link);
    }
}
```